# How does the definition of Eisenstein series relate to the general definition?

Tags: automorphic-forms

In a first course in modular forms, the Eisenstein series of weight 2k are often introduced:

$E_{2k}(z)= \Sigma_{(c,d)=1} 1/2 (cz+d)^{-2k}$.

There is a general definition of Eisenstein series defined in terms of representations induced from Levi subgroups (given, for instance, in some of Arthur's papers on the trace formula). How are these definitions related?

Comment: There are some nice notes by Henry Kim on the Langlands-Shahidi method that discusses the adelic notion of an Eisenstein series, and how the Eisenstein series defined in terms of the trivial representation of the Levi subgroup $\mathrm{GL}_1 \times \mathrm{GL}_1$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ is equal to the usual real analytic Eisenstein series $E(z,s) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{(c,d) = 1} y^s (cz + d)^{-2s}$.

Comment: As @PeterHumphries says, this ultra-classical example is a special case of the general. It certainly does play on many happy coincidences, which is why people noticed it perhaps 100 years before H. Maass' (1949?) invention/discovery of "waveforms", even in the simplest possible case. Some discussion of "transition" from ultra-classical to adele-group stuff is also in an essay of mine: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/12_2_transition_Eis.pdf

Comment: @paulgarrett The link doesn't work. I am interested in your essay.

Comment: Oops, the link is http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/12_2_transition_Eis.pdf